# passenger 4 and the asset pipeline: gzip_static on?

Tags: nginx, passenger

I've read a lot of posts about older versions of Passenger not taking advantage of pre-gzipped assets, is this still the case with Passenger 4? do I need to include something like

```
location /assets  {
    gzip_static on; 
}
```

and compile in the right module, or is all that taken care of now? If not, would the above code do anything or would passenger handle the serving of assets and disregard that code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has got nothing to do with the Phusion Passenger version and everything to do with your Nginx settings. And yes, that single config will take care of it. You may also want to set the caching headers.